# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax elif statement

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I am pretty new to python, I am familiar with Java, C and Ruby.

I tried compiling a script for Kali to fix the RFkill issue for wifi devices since Kali does not have an RFKill.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# replacement for rfkill util, which is missing in kali
# By: Geist

from sys import argv

if(argv[1] == "unblock"):
    x = open("/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2], "w")
x.seek(0)
x.write('0')

elif(argv[1] == "block"):
    x = open("/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2], "w")
x.seek(0)
x.write('1')


print("interface %s %sed" % (argv[2], argv[1]))
```

I did not write this but I am trying to run it and I keep getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax under elif(argv[1] == "block"):

I am assuming this has something to do with improper indentation, if anyone could be as kind to let me know what I am doing wrong and why that would be great!

Comment: Generally, no parentheses are needed in an if-statement in Python (though they are allowed, hence they are not your error).

Comment: You should indeed indent the lines `x.seek and x.write` the same way `x = open...` is indented.

Comment: Please do [read the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) first. It says, among others: "The body of the loop is indented: indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements.".

Comment: The only thing different between the 2 if branches is the write function. Why don't you move the two duplicate lines before the if-statement and only put the write function inside the if statement?

Comment: @Evert: It's certainly a great idea to make the code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but I guess its current structure is a rudimentary way of ensuring Bad Things don't happen if argv[1] is neither "block" or "unblock".

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, yes, that's true.

Comment: You don't need the `x.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Indentation matters in Python**. You have unindented lines between your `if` block and your `elif` block. These will cause a SyntaxError because you've effectively got an `elif` block *without an `if` block.*

Either indent your lines so they match the `if` block, or use a second `if` statement rather than `elif`. Looking at your code, I'd imagine you'll want to indent them otherwise you would get NameErrors. In this case it becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# replacement for rfkill util, which is missing in kali
# By: Geist

from sys import argv

if(argv[1] == "unblock"):
    x = open("/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2], "w")
    x.seek(0)
    x.write('0')

elif(argv[1] == "block"):
    x = open("/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2], "w")
    x.seek(0)
    x.write('1')


print("interface %s %sed" % (argv[2], argv[1]))
```

Comment: This way, it will attempt to write to `x` twice if `argv[1] == "unblock". The indentation mismatch is somewhat ironic.

Comment: @Evert yeah ironic indeed :P Thanks for the comment, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation issue in your code, change according to your algorithm-

For e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# replacement for rfkill util, which is missing in kali
# By: Geist

from sys import argv

if(argv[1] == "unblock"):
    x = open("/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2], "w")
    x.seek(0)
    x.write('0')
elif(argv[1] == "block"):
    x = open("/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2], "w")
    x.seek(0)
    x.write('1')


print("interface %s %sed" % (argv[2], argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly cleaner version of that script.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv

def main():
    try:
        cmd = ("unblock", "block").index(argv[1])
    except ValueError:
        print("Bad command: %s" % argv[1])
        exit(1)

    fname = "/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill%s/soft" % argv[2]
    with open(fname, "w") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(cmd))

    print("Interface %s %sed" % (argv[2], argv[1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```